# How to allow for caps-lock keyboard layout change

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, keyboard-layout

I am using a freshly installed `Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04`, and I want to set `caps-lock` to change keyboard layout (single key, not key combination). I used to have this `Linux-mint`, and I grew used to it. I looked into the setting manager, but there is doesn't accept `caps-lock` as a valid input. I also looked int `gnome-tweak-tools` but there I can't find the keyboard layout switching at all. Is this possible? how?

Comment: Thank you. Please post this as answer for future reference

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could set the corresponding `xkb` option via `dconf-editor`.
Navigate to *org* > *gnome* > *desktop* > *input-sources* and add  `grp:caps_toggle` to your *xkb-options*:

[image]

Note each option is enclosed in single quotes, options are separated by comma+space.

---

On older gnome3 releases you could do that also via *System Settings* > *Keyboard* (or `gnome-control-center keyboard` in terminal) > *Typing* > *Modifiers-only switch to next source* to *Caps Lock*

[image]

This was removed from recent releases ([see sanmai's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331210/22142) for alternatives to `dconf-editor`).

Answer (score 26):

If you're looking for a way to visually edit configuration as in other answer, there's `dconf-editor` supplied with `dconf-tools`:

```
sudo aptitude install dconf-tools
```

If you fancy batch editing needed value, here's how you can read it:

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
```

And here's how to update it:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:caps_toggle']"
```

You may need to logout and log back in for changes to take effect, but in my case changes came into effect immediately.

Other option is to use `gnome-tweaks`.

[image: Location of the "Additional Layout Options" button in the interface of Gnome Tweaks.]

[image: Menu showing an option to use CAPS LOCK as a keyboard switch.]

Comment: It looks like `gnome-tweak-tool` now lacks menu `Swithing to another layout`. Your first approach works

Comment: @Herrgott, On my machine, running gnome-tweaks 3.30.2, Under the top level menu `Keyboard & Mouse` there is a button `Additional Layout Options` which opens a modal dialog box with the options shown here for `Typing`. @sanmai, it would be helpful if you could update your answer.

Comment: @LeoRochael I guess you made a mistake with mention. I haven't posted an answer. I'm not using gnome and this is one of the reasons

Comment: @LeoRochael Done, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

In Cinnamon on Linux Mint (or other Gnome like):

```
Keyboard->Layouts->Options->
                         |->Switching to another layout->Caps Lock
                         |->Use keyboard alternative ... LED->Caps Lock
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this just a text-based description of [sanmai's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331210/117549)?

Comment: Nope. He's using gnome-tweaks but all rly simpler.